# jQuery Datatable row grouping total items display "Show 1 to n entries"

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to achieve the row group,

I found this js http://cdn.rawgit.com/ashl1/datatables-rowsgroup/v1.0.0/dataTables.rowsGroup.js plugin to achieve like below,
But when I am using this plugin, number of entries is showing wrong.

Here is my sample code

```
<table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>First Group</th>
            <th>Second Group</th>
            <th>Third</th>
           
          </tr>
        </thead>  
        <tbody>
          
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

JS Code:

```
var data = [{"first":"subgroup1","second":"group1","third":"third data"},
{"first":"subgroup1","second":"group1","third":"third data"},
{"first":"subgroup2","second":"group2",
"third":"lorem ipsum data"},
{"first":"subgroup2","second":"group2",
"third":"lorem ipsum data"},
                ]

$('#example').DataTable({
columns:[
    {
    name:"first",
    data:"first"
  },
  {
    name:"second",
    data:"second"
  },
  {
    name:"thirddata",
    data:"third"
  },
],
    data:data,
  rowsGroup: [
  'first:name',
   'thirddata:name'
  ]

});
```

Updated in JS Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/r2f87hg6/2/

[image]

Please suggest with this datatable to display number of entries by grouped.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `number of entries is showing wrong`? What is the correct answer then?

Comment: `subgroup1` related item is only one record. But I need to send indiviudally for rowgroup. So in this case it is showing as 4 entires. But really have 2 entries. i.e `subgroup1` and `subgroup2`

Comment: Look. We have 4 elements in `data` array. Then we "group" them. In your example we use grouping: `rowsGroup:['first:name','thirddata:name']` (so column 1 and 3 are grouped, column 2 not). In that case you will have resulting 4 elements, because column 2 is not grouped. It is expected behavior. For this script all your data is "data".

Comment: And let's take a look if we change grouping to: `rowsGroup:['first:name','second:name','thirddata:name']` (so we need data to be compact). You will see only 2 rows as a result: https://jsfiddle.net/yuebnzwp/  and this is also expected behavior.

Comment: Oh... in my example we have 2 rows, but 4 elements... It seems this library counts only incoming data.

Comment: Yes, It seems. how we can show correct entries.

Comment: First, how to understand what is "correct". See example: https://jsfiddle.net/yuebnzwp/1/  How many "correct" rows here? 2 or 3? (despite of that last cell is not merged, but it should?..)

Comment: Last cell also should be merged. "correct" rows only 2.

Comment: Then your question sounds like "rewrite/update library, so I can use it in my project" ('cause current lib do it in it's own way). I think, SO will not help you, because it can take long time. But I wish you luck. Sorry for not able to help now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221307/discussion-between-krishna38-and-anton).